# for i in range(len(val)): TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying to enter this form but i am getting this error
for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
i did some research and i think its because its a number and thats why its not entering the form
but i don't know what to do then

````
import pandas as pd

from idlelib import browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager import driver
from idlelib.multicall import i
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/hamudsadek/Desktop/data.xlsx')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='/Users/hamudsadek/Desktop/chromedriver')



browser.get('https://dropkicks.digitalgmg.com/dk-register.php?event=dk21-nike-dunk')


for i in df.index:
    entry = df.loc[i]


    name_input = browser.find_element_by_name('full_name')
    name_input.send_keys(entry['full name'])


    email_input = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
    email_input.send_keys(entry['email'])

    
    phone_input = browser.find_element_by_name('mobile_number')
    phone_input.send_keys(entry['phone'])

    age_input = browser.find_element_by_name('age')
    age_input.send_keys(entry['age'])

    
    gender_select = Select(browser.find_elements_by_name('gender'))
    gender_select.select_by_value(entry['gender'])```
````

Comment: `for i in range(len(val)):` where is this in your code snippet?

Comment: no thats the error

Comment: How is `df.index` defined?

Comment: i get the error above once it reaches the part to fill the phone number

Comment: It's a good idea to include the full error stack, otherwise it's just a guesswork.

Comment: File "/Users/hamudsadek/rafflelist/basketballista/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    phone_input.send_keys(entry['phone'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="mobile_number"]').send_keys(8944625345.05)
```

The error means exactly that , try the above code and you will get that error, convert it to string first .

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="mobile_number"]').send_keys(str(8944625345.05))
```

If you check the implementation of send_keys:

the implementation of sending_key is

```
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
                  {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
                   'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
```

where keys_to_typing will itearte through each val:

```
def keys_to_typing(value):
    """Processes the values that will be typed in the element."""
    typing = []
    for val in value:
        if isinstance(val, Keys):
            typing.append(val)
        elif isinstance(val, int):
            val = str(val)
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])
        else:
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])
    return typing
```

### it should be string or integer , you can see the typing code converts to string only int and key not float

## Solution:

```
 phone_input.send_keys(str(entry['phone']))
```

Comment: ok this worked but its not typing the numbers in order for example i put on the excel 971507654 instead it puts 456705197

Comment: str(entry['phone'])  and entry['phone'] print this first and see what you are getting